# Web API - Como validar o modelo a partir do DataAnnotation.Remote()?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Tenho o seguinte modelo (DTO):

```
public class PessoaAcesso : Pessoa
{
    [Remote("LoginUnico", "Pessoa", ErrorMessage = "Esse Login já existe! Escolha outro.")]
    public virtual string Login { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

No meu ApiController (WebAPI) implementei o método "LoginUnico" para testes:

```
public JsonResult<bool> LoginUnico(string login)
{
    return Json(false);
}
```

Porém ao fazer a requisição via POST não está acionando o método. Era para ele rejeitar a inserção da nova pessoa, porém está aceitando.

Quem já tenha implementado o Remote() no WebAPI pode me orientar.

Comment: Já anotou `[HttpPost]` na `Action` antes de testar?

Answer (score 1):

Anote seu método com `[HttpPost]`:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult<bool> LoginUnico(string login)
{
    return Json(false);
}
```